# Youtube video as a site background (tubular.js) shows on top of my other components instead of in the back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tubular

I have a webpage that uses tubular.js script to show youtube video as a site background. There's a sentence on [tubular page](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/):

> First, it assumes you have a single wrapper element under the body tag
>   that envelops all of your website content. It promotes that wrapper to
>   z-index: 99 and position: relative.

So following that, I wrote a simple html/css code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#logocontainer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    margin-top: -35px;/* half of #content height*/
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 75px;
}


</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="logocontainer">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>


</div> <!--wrapper-->   
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.tubular.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var options = {
                    videoId : '9JXVUP1hyxA',
                    start : 1
                };
                $('body').tubular(options);
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but now, when I run it - I see only youtube video without my logo on top... I know the logo is there, because when I comment out the youtube script I can see it, however I don't see it when the video is present. I tried to add `z-index:99` to `#logo` but that didn't do any magic... Can you help me with that?

EDIT:

As A. Wolff suggested below, I added to my css:

```
#wrapper{
    z-index:99;
    position: relative;
}
```

still though - no good results, video is still on top..

Comment: But have you tried to set z-index: 99 **and** position: relative for `#wrapper` element?

Comment: Is it me or would a video as a background be rather annoying and distracting?

Comment: @EdHeal Depending video i would say but anyway wouldn't work on all device especially the ones which don't allow autoplay mode for video

Comment: @A.Wolff I updated my question with your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work..

Comment: As you can see, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/a946gL5c/

Comment: Ok, it fixed my problem, Idk how to mark this comment as the suggested solution, if you put it as an answer I'll mark it for future users as resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see in their own Tubular they use this little script...

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var options = { videoId: 'ab0TSkLe-E0', start: 3 };
$('#wrapper').tubular(options);
// f-UGhWj1xww cool sepia hd
// 49SKbS7Xwf4 beautiful barn sepia
```

});

Just adding this keeps everything on top.
Use the code in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/pdqmw6zp/5/)** as a sample.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your must use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) with position: relative/absolute.
Also your z-index in video must be less than in your blocks.

```
video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks, check my updated question, one of the users suggested that, but that didn't help me unfortunately..

Comment: @randomuser1 - please, also try to set z-index to your div's.